# How and When can I use &lt or &gt?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm fairly new to Javascript, and just now learned about `&lt` and `&gt`. I don't how to use them or how they would look like in javascript. Can you give me an example? And is it better to use it than `<` or `>`?

Answer (score 4):

`&lt;` and `&gt;` are HTML representations of the `<` and `>` characters. You should use them when creating HTML where you want these characters to appear. Otherwise, they are interpreted as syntactic elements by the HTML engine.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have to dynamically create a text box in JavaScript and the contents of the textbox include something like `"Do not forget to use <diamond brackets> in your HashMap declaration"`, i.e. any string that contains an opening or closing diamond (aka angle) bracket. Then here you will have to use `&lt;` and `&gt;`, else the browser will parse them as HTML tags and produce an erroneous page.